# Oracle: What is the correct way to create initial schemas and data?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

I've been trying to setup an Oracle database for certification/study purposes. I have been utilizing the docker image building script in my project to help create an easily recyclable database and I'm having some trouble creating my initial schemas.

The [README documentation I found](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance#running-scripts-after-setup-and-on-startup) states that I should be able to create a number of setup scripts that are kicked off automatically when the database is ready, all I need to do is place them in the `/opt/oracle/scripts/setup/` directory.

I tried doing that [in my Dockerfile](https://github.com/paul-nelson-baker/oracle-12-playground/blob/9b57bdef96b37acb0be44475d76504b6f3e3f694/Dockerfile#L17), and while they do execute they don't succeed with even the most trivial example I came up with.

For example, I tried creating a user named `student` and immediately came across an error specific to [Oracle 12's multi-tennancy](https://github.com/paul-nelson-baker/oracle-12-playground/blob/9b57bdef96b37acb0be44475d76504b6f3e3f694/sample-data-generator/templates/v1_inital-user-creation.sql.tmpl#L8). Not really wanting to care about it, since it's not something covered by the 1Z0-071 certification, I took the black-magic answer and moved on.

But I was immediately blocked *again* by an even stranger error [in my code](https://github.com/paul-nelson-baker/oracle-12-playground/blob/622a16c673ac20b05453d7b0caa4a5975c3ff0ac/sample-data-generator/templates/v2_define-sample-data.sql.tmpl#L12).

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE simpledata.simpledata_pk_sequence;

INSERT INTO simpledata.simpledata (id, text)
VALUES (simpledata.simpledata_pk_sequence.nextval, 'Hi, I''m Paul')
                   *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'
```

Which seems to point to the fact that I'm doing something out-right wrong. I should be able to initialize the database with whatever arbitrary users and data. This leads me to believe I'm either missing configuration steps, I'm using the wrong user, or something else entirely that I'm not aware of.

What is the correct way to run an arbitrary setup script in Oracle 12?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will cover what you ask, because it looks like a question with different answers as alternatives to do it.

Anyway, your scripts look ok, except for the fact that you are missing something in the second one respect to the first one.

Script

```
 {{ with .SimpleData }}

CREATE USER simpledata IDENTIFIED BY {{ RandomPassword }} DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP PROFILE DEFAULT QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS ;
CREATE TABLE simpledata.simpledata (
    id NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    text VARCHAR2(20)
);
CREATE SEQUENCE simpledata.simpledata_pk_sequence;

{{ range .Items }}
INSERT INTO simpledata.simpledata (id, text)
VALUES (simpledata.simpledata_pk_sequence.nextval, '{{ . }}');
{{ end }}
```

If you ask me how is the way to create schemas and data, I would go for creating the things separately and in the right order:

- Schemas
- Sequences
- Tables
- DML scripts ( Insert, Update, etc..)
- Functions , Procedures and Packages.

Example user creation in your case

```
SQL> create user simpledata identified by "Passw_1" default tablespace users temporary tablespace temp account unlock profile default quota unlimited on users;

User created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.09
SQL>
```